# *Swift iOS* Container View inside UIViewController PUSH View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a UIViewController with a Container View. The container view has a navigation controller with which I can display different scenes within the main view.

Structure:

```
MainVC
1SubVC (Container View) inside MainVC
2SubVC (ContainerView) inside MainVC
```

**Now my question: Can I execute a function from my MainVC so that the 1SubVC pushes to the 2SubVC?**

Something like ->

```
class MainVC {
   1SubVC().doThisPushFunc()
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I feel that the case of using any navigation controller-based sub VC is unfamiliar. Did you happen to try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

*For everyone who is looking for a similar solution.*

The solution was the **NotificationCenter**.

1. Listener für Notification in **SubView1** in ViewDidLoad
2. objc func in **SubView1** to execute the notification
3. Call the notification from **MainVC**

Answer (score 0):

By saying "push" I'm assuming you're going to use a UINavigationController and push a view controller onto the navigation stack. The main reason you would use a UINavigationController class is to have helpful functionality like the animation when you're pushing to a new view controller or if you're needing a top navigation bar.

If you're just wanting to go from showing 1SubVC to 2SubVC, then replace the container view.
If you're wanting to have MainVC notify 1SubVC to make the `navigationController.pushViewController()` call then access an instance of 1SubVC() so you can call the push method
e.g. Inside of MainVC

```
    let oneSubVC = 1SubVC()
    oneSubVC.navigationController.pushViewController(ViewController(), true)
```